# cakephp sum() on single field

Tags: cakephp

I have searched high and low on how to just get a total of a field called points. I just need one total figure but the best I can get is a list of records from the Points table with the associated records from the Members.

```
    $totalPoints = $this->Member->Point->find('all', array(
               array('fields' => array('sum(Point.points)   AS Point.ctotal'))));
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: And what cakephp version? You should *always* mention the version you are using

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not using virtualFields as documented and suggested by the docs?
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

```
$this->Member->Point->virtualFields['total'] = 'SUM(Point.points)';
$totalPoints = $this->Member->Point->find('all', array('fields' => array('total')));
```

This is way cleaner.

Also note the double array you got there in your $options array (`...find('all', array(array(...`). And how I used only a single/flat array.
This is the reason why your SUM() call as fields does not work.

Comment: I refined the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a much better understanding now of virtualFields. Little more to it then I thought

Answer (score 3):

mark's answer above is right. I just want to add that you can do this:

```
$totalPoints = $this->Member->Point->find('first', array(
               array('fields' => array('sum(Point.points) AS Point__ctotal'))));
```

`$totalPoints` will be have this:

```
$totalPoints['Point']['ctotal']
```

Comment: might work in some cases - but thats not how virtual fields really should be set up. I would go with the documented version.

Comment: that for the reply, when I used the above code I had to use $redeemedTotal[0][0]['Point__redeemedTotal'] in the view. Where as the other example I use $redeemedTotal[0]['Point']['Point__redeemedTotal'] is there something missing? I would like your solution using $totalPoints['Point']['ctotal'] as it is easier to read in the view.

Comment: worked for me as it allowed me to put a condition in on-the-fly

Answer (score 0):

Another clean way without outputting an array

```
$this->Member->Point->virtualFields = array('total' => 'SUM(Point.points)');
$total = $this->Member->Point->field('total');
```