# calculate the Sum of note pupils in class

Tags: cakephp

I have two model pupils(..., note, class_id) and class .
I want to search the sum of the scores of pupils in each class.
I tried that but not worked :

```
$this->Class->Puplis->find('first', array(
                     'fields' => array('sum(Puplis.note) AS total'),
                     'conditions' => array('Puplis.class_id' => $id),
               ));
```

Comment: SHouldnt be first, but all. And you should use virtual fields if this is 2.x - also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cakephp sum() on single field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693008/cakephp-sum-on-single-field)

Comment: Potentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693008/cakephp-sum-on-single-field

Comment: thanks for every body I found the solution:

Comment: `$totalNotes = $this->Class->Pupils->find('all', array('fields' => array('total'),
                                                       'group' => 'Pupils.Class_id'
  ));
var_dump($totalNotes);`